# runtime error 13 type mismatch excel 2007

Tags: vba

I am currently learning to code in excel VBA and I wrote the following code but when I run it, I get a runtime error 13 type mismatch. Any Ideas

```
Sub dennis()
Sheets(Sheet2).Select
Range("E1").Select

Do Until Selection.Offset(0, -4).Value = ""

Selection.Value = Selection.Offset(0, -4).Value & " " & Selection.Offset(0, -3).Value
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
Range("F1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not an answer, but generally speaking, not good to rely on `Select`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for a good explanation.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your sheet is not named correctly:

Change `Sheets(Sheet2).Select` to `Sheets("Sheet2").Select`

Comment: Or `Sheet2.Select` to refer to the sheet by its `.CodeName` property.

Answer (score 0):

The error is the argument of the property Sheet. The argument must be an index.

To select the sheet number 2, you can write 
    `Sheets(2).Select`  or     `Sheets("Sheet2").select`